# Make HTML element respond only to click event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi do you make the first

in the code below only respond to click() event? Now dblclick() is also catching the first

.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("p:not(#clickonly)".dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
$("p#clickonly").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id='clickonly'>If you double-click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
```

:not does not work.

Comment: :not does not work. so it's not duplicate question.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you're using it wrong. Show your code.

Comment: @JJJ I tried "p:not(#one)" and "p:not(p#one)".

Comment: The id is `#clickonly`, not `#one`. **Edit your question** and add a [mcve].

Comment: oh sorry I mean "p:not(#clickonly)" and "p:not(p#clickonly)".

Comment: ...and `p:not(#clickonly)` works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/c8wjx6qp/

Comment: p:not(#clickonly) still catching single and double click, the 1st <p> only click, 2nd and 3rd <p> double click.

Comment: Look, you *really* have to show your code if you want help. Seriously. You probably apply it to both selectors when you should only apply it to the doubleclick event. But that's just guessing, can't say anything certain without **seeing the code**.

Comment: That is what I did applied it to only double click.

Comment: Well, good luck figuring it out on your own. Can't help if you're not willing to cooperate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're code is correct, Javascript can't sense whether the double click was for double click only, when you double click it catches the first click and trigger that click event for p#clickonly.  Your question is not a duplicate the given link does not explain that behavior.